# How can I display specific items on a table based on dropdownlistfor selection in MVC?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to display a table with all the cars that include the specifications selected on the dropdowns once a submit button is clicked. I am currently able to display a table from a partial view when I click the button but I am filtering my results and I am not sure how to do it.

This is my view

```
@model IgnitionHub2._0.Models.Car
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Car Search Page";
}

<h2>Cars</h2>
<div class="center-div">
    <div class="form-inline" , id="ddlCars">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CarID, new SelectList(Model.CarList, "CarID", "Model.Name"), "Select Car", new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Model.MakeID, new SelectList(Model.MakeList, "MakeID", "Name"), "Select Make", new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ModelID, new SelectList(Model.ModelList, "ModelID", "Name"), "Select Model", new { @class = "form-control" })
        <button id="search">Search</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="searchResults">

</div>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>


<script>
    var url = '@Url.Action("DisplaySearchResults", "Car")';
$('#search').click(function() {
  var modelID = $('#CarID').val();
  $('#searchResults').load(url, { searchText: modelID });
})
</script>
```

This is my partial View

```
@model IEnumerable<IgnitionHub2._0.Models.Car>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Year)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Color)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Mileage)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BodyType)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Drive)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Available)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CarLot.LotName)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Year)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Color)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Mileage)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BodyType)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Drive)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Available)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Model.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CarLot.LotName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.CarID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.CarID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.CarID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

This is my controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{

    var cars = db.Cars.Include(c => c.Model).Include(c => c.CarLot);
    var makeList = db.Makes.ToList();
    var modelList = db.Models.ToList();
    var ViewModel = new Car
    {
    CarList = cars,
    MakeList = makeList,
    ModelList= modelList
    };

    return View(ViewModel);
}

public ActionResult _Index()
{
    var cars = new List<Car>(); 
    return PartialView(cars);
}
public ActionResult DisplaySearchResults(string searchText)
{
    var model = db.Cars.Include(c => c.Model.Make).ToList();// build list based on parameter searchText
    return PartialView("_Index", model);
 }
```

Please Help! Thank you in advance!

Comment: But what exactly is the problem?

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro no error with the code, I just currently get a list of all the cars regardless of the selection in the dropdownlist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well since you are making a GET request you can add more parameters to your DisplaySearchResults.

```
public ActionResult DisplaySearchResults(string CarID, string MakeID, string ModelID)
{
  var model = db.Cars.Where(c => c.Model.Make == MakeID && c.Model == ModelID && 
   c.CarID == CarID).ToList();

  return PartialView("_Index", model);
}
```

But make sure to send your http request with the querystring key names are same as the parameter name expected in your backend, something like:

```
var modelID = $('#CarID').val();
var makeID = $('#CarID').val();
var modelID = $('#CarID').val();
$('#searchResults').load(url, { CarID: carID, MakeID: makeID, ModelID: modelID });
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I was able to add this but I get some null values when I click on submit. I will continue to look into that but Thank you so much for this! it has been extremely helpful.